# WP 8 - How to Open Menu with Application Bar Icon Button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

My question is clear and short i think. How can i open application bar with applicationbar icon button ?

You know, we use the application bar like this ;

```
<shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="ApplicationBar1" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True"  ForegroundColor="SeaShell" BackgroundColor="DarkGreen">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar_menu.png" Text="Menu" Click="OpenMenu"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar_refresh.png" Text="Live" Click="GetLiveMatchesClick"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar.speakerphone.png" Text="Betting" Click="GetBettingMatchesClick"/>
</shell:ApplicationBar>
```

You see on above, I need to trigger or do something when i click Menu "ApplicationBarIconButton". I need to open menu with it. You know there is three dots icon on application bar but i want to open the my menu, my application bar with that icon.

How can i handle that ? Please help me about it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There is no property or method available that will do this for you. [See the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.iapplicationbar%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

The only way I see is to implement your own ApplicationBar.

Comment: Can't i write something to trigger opening menu on my OpenMenu event ?

Comment: As far as I know: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/86484773-22f1-4b4a-9355-d1a61f77d912/ui-automation-for-windows-phone-8 there is no build in support for UI automation. The event is raised when the bar opens, you cannot use it the other way around.